# Are there customizable progress bars for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, progress-bar, uiprogressview

UIProgressView doesn't allow any customization. I know it's not exactly something complicated, but still I'd prefer to use an open sourced solution rather than re-inventing my own wheel.

Are there any?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are many at [Cocoa Controls](http://cocoacontrols.com/search?q=progress), some are more customizable than others. I like [ATMHud](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/atmhud).

[image: PDColoredProgressview]
[image: DDProgressView]
[image: ATMHud]
[image: SSPieProgressView]
[...](http://cocoacontrols.com/search?q=progress)

Answer (score 2):

Github is usually a good source for such OS projects. Here's one possibility:

[CMTwoToneProgressBar](https://github.com/cmezak/CMTwoToneProgressBar)